# atexit handler not responding to signals

Tags: python, windows, signals, interrupt, kill

I have two python files:

**a.py:**

```
import subprocess, time, os, signal

myprocess = subprocess.Popen("b.py", shell=True)
time.sleep(2)
os.kill(myprocess.pid, signal.SIGTERM)
```

**b.py:**

```
import atexit

def cleanup():
    print "Cleaning up things before the program exits..."

atexit.register(cleanup)

print "Hello world!"

while True:
    pass
```

`a.py` is spawning `b.py` and after 2 seconds it is killing the process. The problem is that I want the `cleanup` function to call in `b.py` before it gets killed but I can't get it to work.

I also tried `SIGKILL` and `SIGINT` in the `os.kill` function but neither worked for me.

**Current output (a.py):**

```
Hello, World!
(2 seconds later, program ends)
```

**Expected output (a.py):**

```
Hello, World!
(2 seconds later)
Cleaning up things before the program exits...
(program ends)
```

Comment: What platform are you on?

Comment: Windows, but it could potentially be Linux as well in the future.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a different signal for Windows platform: `signal.CTRL_C_EVENT`

Put some more sleep into `a.py`, otherwise the child process does not get a chance to clean up before the parent process exits:

```
import subprocess, time, os, signal
myprocess = subprocess.Popen("b.py", shell=True)
time.sleep(2)
os.kill(myprocess.pid, signal.CTRL_C_EVENT)
time.sleep(2)
```

I also want to discourage you from using the shell, if you don't actually need the shell features:

```
import subprocess, time, os, signal, sys
myprocess = subprocess.Popen([sys.executable, "b.py"])
```

**Linux/macOS** users: `signal.CTRL_C_EVENT` doesn't exist, you want `signal.SIGINT`.

Comment: I see why this makes sense, but it still isn't working... Have you tested it yourself, and does it work for you?

Comment: Yes I tested it myself and it works on macOS.  I don't have a windows box available.

Comment: Actually, could you try using `signal.CTRL_C_EVENT` or `signal.CTRL_BREAK_EVENT`?  This stuff is very platform dependent, signals have different availability on Windows.

Comment: That works! Do you know if `signal.CTRL_C_EVENT` works on linux? Thank you very much! :)

Comment: No (it doesn't even exist on Linux).  `signal.CTRL_C_EVENT` is only for Windows.

Comment: Right, thanks! I probably won't need to worry about Linux for the next few months anyway.